# R function ecdf

Tags: r, ecdf

```
xs <- seq(floor(min(fheight)),ceiling(max(fheight)),0.01)
plot(xs, ecdf(fheight)(xs),type = "l", xlab = "height in inches",ylab = "F(x)")
```

What is the purpose of `(xs)` in `ecdf(fheight)(xs)`

Answer (score 1):

`ecdf(fheight)` returns a function. Yes, it's a bit odd having a function that takes arguments to return another function.

`xs` are the arguments to the resulting function.

So `ecdf(fheight)(xs)` will return the values of the cumulative density function `ecdf(fheight)` at the values of `xs`.

From the R help available from `?ecdf` you can see this:

> **Value**
>
> For `ecdf`, a function of class "`ecdf`"